# How to access and change an input variable in R Shiny server.r

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if this is a common question, but it's driving me nuts.  I need to add an actionButton to a Shiny UI that triggers a file save.  The actual file save command depends upon which tab of a tabPanel is open, and I can get that information via the tabPanel id.  The problem I'm having is with accessing the state of the actionButton and resetting it afterwards.

In ui.r, I have something like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("myTitle"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("",
            actionButton("save", "Save File"),

            # test to make sure the button is working
            verbatimTextOutput("sb")    # it increments when clicked
        )
    )
))
```

In server.r, I'm trying to do this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # test to make sure the button is working
    output$sb <- renderPrint({ input$save })     # increments when clicked

    # here is the problem code:
    if(input$save > 0) {                         # button was clicked, so...
        input$save <- 0                          # reset the flag
        print("HERE")                            # and do something else
    }
})
```

Of course, I'll check the status of the tabPanel instead of printing "HERE", which will likely generate another question if I get past this problem.  How do I access and change the value of input$save in the server.r code?  There is no evidence that the code inside the if() conditional statement is being executed, so I assume that the logical test is either not being performed, or is returning FALSE even though the value of input$save increments whenever the button is clicked.

Thanks for any advice.  As is probably apparent, I'm very new to Shiny and am finding it rather opaque, so far.

Best,
--Mike C.

Answer (score 5):

If your code needs to reexecute whenever an input changes, it can't just be inside your server function like you have the `if` right now. You need to put that inside an observe block:

```
observe({
  if (input$save == 0)
    return()

  isolate({
    # Do your saving in here
  })
})
```

You absolutely don't need to reset the value of input$save to 0. I believe that so wholeheartedly that I specifically left that ability out of the framework. The actual value of `input$save` is meaningless EXCEPT for the value 0 which simply means "the button has NEVER been clicked"; for every other value, the value itself is not important, just that it changed. Every time you get to the `# Do your saving in here` line, it means the user clicked the Save button. It shouldn't matter to you whether it is the 1st or 100th time it was clicked; the fact is that the user just clicked it and you should now save.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that code is only getting run once when you start the `shinyServer`. I think you need to be inside a `reactive` block in order to run on model changes. Otherwise that block of code as it stands now will never get re-evaluated.